# Add string in array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have following array:

```
$DS = array(
    'name' => 'kim',
    'star' => 'singh'

);
```

I want adding new array in it. this array: `'relation' => '100','original' => '1'`

Finally, it will look like:

```
$DS = array(
    'name' => 'kim',
    'star' => 'singh',
    'relation' => '100',
    'original' => '1'

);
```

**My tried as:**

```
$DS = array(
    'name' => 'kim',
    'star' => 'singh'

);
array_push($DS, array(
    'relation' => '100',
    'original' => '1'
));

echo '<pre>';
print_r($DS);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [name] => kim
    [star] => singh
    [0] => Array
        (
            [relation] => 100
            [original] => 1
        )

)
```

Demo:http://codepad.viper-7.com/ouzBxN

How can done it, please give me example.

Comment: `$DS['relation'] = '100'; DS['original'] = '1';`

Comment: for u... If I am correct... array push for next row.,,. not for another column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`array_merge()`](https://www.php.net/array_merge)

```
$new_array = array_merge($DS, array(
    'relation' => '100',
    'original' => '1'
));
```

Answer (score 0):

This works Fine:

```
$array1 = array(
        'name' => 'kim',
        'star' => 'singh'

    );

    $array2 = array(
        'relation' => '100',
        'original' => '1'

    );
    $array3 = $array1+$array2;

    print_r($array3);
```